# Unable to install Micro Focus ALM Microsoft Excel Add-in

Tags: microsoft-excel

Unable to install HP ALM Microsoft Excel Add-in.
I am using ALM 12.60. 
I need to upload test cases from Excel to ALM;
for that I have to install HP ALM Microsoft Excel Add-in.

Please find the version detail:
 - ALM Microsoft excel add-in: 12.60
 - Microsoft excel version: 2016 with 64 bit
 - OS: Windows 10 with 64 bit

When I try to install the ALM Excel add-in then I get the below error:

> The installation of ExcelSetupx64 appears to have failed. Do you want to continue the installation?

Refer screenshot for reference:
[image: ALM Error screenshot]

Comment: According to the information on download page of the add-in, you must install Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (any version later than 10.0.50325). To install, go to [Microsoft Download Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48217). Please open Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features to have a check. You can also [perform a clean boot in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows) . Check if you can install the add-in successfully under clean boot mode.

Comment: Thanks for the response but still I am getting same error.
Installed  Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime as suggested
Also performed clean boot and tried installing under clean boot mode but still it is thowing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I am closing this ticket as this issue got resolved.
This add-in was getting blocked by the anti-virus installed in my system.